# MSIX SDK How to install

Tags: msix

I want to make a Msix Package using this neu command but do not know how to install this sdk and get the commands in the command line.

makemsix.exe pack -d  -p  [options]

can anyone help me please? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to install Windows App Certification Kit from the Win SDK.

Then you will find the "MakeAppX.exe" (which contrary to its name is actually able to create MSIX) in the default location:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit\
```

Comment: Is this the same as "OptionId.WindowsSoftwareLogoToolkit"?